# Dollar sign followed by a square bracket in a template string

Tags: javascript, string, templates, syntax, ecmascript-6

I was messing around with some ES6-code and came across this

```
let vendors = ['ms', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o'];
let root = window || global;
let performance = window.performance || {};
if (!performance.now) {
  vendors.some(function(vendor) {
    performance.now = performance[`$[vendor}Now`];
    ...
```

I can guess what the code-piece below does, but what kind of library/syntax is it? It's not something I have ever seen before, and it's not pure ES6, right?

```
`$[vendor}Now`
```

Comment: Looks like a mistake. Ask the author of the code.

Comment: In addition to being a syntax error, all this is unnecessary, since webkit is the only platform that apparently ever used `performance.webkitNow`, and that was way back in v20.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that this is a syntax error. The correct thing should be:

```
`${vendor}Now`
```

This is the dollar expression as it is mentioning here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

> Template strings are enclosed by the back-tick (`` ` ``) (grave accent) character instead of double or single quotes. Template strings can contain place holders. These are indicated by the Dollar sign and curly braces (${expression}).

The square bracket in a template string is a mistake.

More specifically if you have:

```
var expression = 'test';

console.log(`string text ${expression} string text`); //Correct syntax
```

The above code will export: "string text test string text"

But the below code with one opening square bracket and one closing [curly bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket)

```
var expression = 'test';

console.log(`string text $[expression} string text`); //Wrong syntax
```

Will just export: "string text $[expression} string text"